# ListBox select item with right click UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, listbox

I need to select item with right-click in the ListBox control.
How to do it in UWP?

Thank you.
Best wishes.

Comment: As @lindexi said, you can subscribe the RightTapped event for your each item, then set the SelectedItem of ListBox as sender in the event, does this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `RightTapped` event in your item.

```xml
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind TheData}">            

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="#FFda2a5c" RightTapped="GridColection_OnRightTapped">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And then you can write the `GridColection_OnRightTapped` in your code and handle the right click event